Uploading image to AWS S3 using boto3 won't display in browser window, but uploading the image through the AWS console works fine
So I have an AWS lambda with the following code:
result = s3.put_object(
    Bucket = "my-bucket",
    Key = "image.png"
    Body = decoded_image,
    ContentType = "image/png",
    Tagging = "Key1=Value1"
)

And the image gets successfully uploaded to the bucket, but when I try to access the image in a browser, the file downloads instead.
If I upload the image to the same bucket directly from the AWS console, I can view the image in a browser window.
Everything looks the same for the properties/permissions of the 2 images.
Here is the permission on the bucket:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}


So I was able to access the image in a browser using this url:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/image.png
On the image property page it shows this url, which doesn't work:
https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image.png
